# jquery ajax form submit plugin not posting file input

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

I've got this form:

```
<form id="imageinputpopup" class=suggestionsubmit style="display: none">
    <span>Add a thing!</span><br/>
    <label>url: </label><input name="imageurl" type="url"><br/>
    <label>file: </label><input name="imagefile" type="file"><br/>
    <input type='hidden' name='schoolid' class="schoolid">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And this document.ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.schoolid').val(get_gmap_value('school_id'));

    $(".allow-submission").live('click', function(){
        if($(this).attr('inputtype')=="colorpicker"){
            .....
        } else if($(this).attr('inputtype')=="image"){
            remove_hidden("#imageinputpopup");
            add_fieldname($(this), $("#imageinputpopup"));
            $("#imageinputpopup").dialog();
        } else if($(this).attr('inputtype')=="text"){
            ....
        } else {
            //nothing
        }
    });

    $(".suggestionsubmit").submit(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).html());
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            url: '/save-school-suggestion/',
            type: 'post',
            success: function(response){
                response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                // Check for login redirect.
//                if ( response.requireLogin ) {
//                    alert('Sign up or log in to save your answer');
//                } else {
                    $('.suggestionsubmit').dialog('close');
//                }
            }
        });
    });
});

    function add_fieldname(element, addto){
        var elementname = document.createElement('input');
        elementname.type = 'hidden';
        elementname.name = 'fieldname';
        elementname.value = element.attr('fieldname').replace(' ', '_');
        $(elementname).addClass('fieldname');
        addto.append(elementname);
    }

    function remove_hidden(element){
        $(element+' .fieldname').remove();
    }
```

But the file field isn't showing up server side.

Why?

I found this in the documentation:

Why aren't all my input values posted?
jQuery form serialization aheres closely to the HTML spec. Only successful controls are valid for submission.

But I don't understand why my file control would be invalid.
I have another submission form in a different place on my site that is almost identical and works perfectly...

EDIT: this is the other form that does work (it has some extra stuff in it, but the form tag just has an id, like the problem one, and the input tags are the same).

```
<form id="photos-submission-form6">

    <input type="hidden" name="section" value="photos">
    <input type="hidden" name="school" id="photos-submit-school6">


    <div style="margin-bottom: .5em">
            <p style="position: relative; width:80%; font-size: 14px; display: inline" id="photos-anonymity-header6">Post as: null</p>
            <img id="helpicon6" src="/static/img/help-icon.png" style="float: right; cursor: pointer; padding-left:1em;">
            <div id="explanation6" style="display: none; padding:1em; background-color:white; border:2px solid gray; position: absolute;z-index:30; right:5px; top:5px">For more posting options, <a id="profilelink6" href="/profile/">fill out your profile</a></div>
        </div>
    <div id="photos-anonymity-select6" style="margin-bottom: .75em; width:412px" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 100%; "></a></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="photos-anonymity-level6" name="anonymity-level" value="username">
        <span style="line-height: 40px;">
        <label class="photouploadlabel">URL</label><input type="text" name="image-url" style="width: 335px"><br>
        <label class="photouploadlabel">File</label><input type="file" name="image-file" style="width: 335px"><br>
        <label class="photouploadlabel">Caption</label><input type="text" id="image-caption6" name="image-caption" style="width: 335px; color: rgb(128, 128, 128); ">
        </span>


    <div style="height: 30px; margin-top: 1em; width: 413px;">
            <label id="photos-tagsbutton6" style="margin-right: .5em; cursor: pointer; vertical-align: bottom; float:left; line-height: 1.8em;">Tags</label>
        <input id="photos-tagsinput6" style="display: none;" type="text" name="tags">
        <button id="send-photos-suggestion6" disabled="" style="float:right; position: relative; bottom: 7px; right: -4px;" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="true"><span class="ui-button-text">Post</span></button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Is this the actual code or an example? Should `class=suggestionsubmit` be `class="suggestionsubmit"` in the form?

Comment: This is the actual code, and yes, it should be, but changing it didn't make a difference, and surprisingly didn't break the code in the first place.

Comment: Have you got a functional image uploader somewhere else (there's no problem with directory's write rights, `file_max_size` etc.)? What's different with this form compared to another, you said: "I have another submission form in a different place on my site that is almost identical–––"? Also add `method="post"` to your form. Default is `get`. I doubt it helps but it's worth a try anyway.

Comment: Yes, the image uploader works (for example, if you just put in a url I get the file server side and save it). I'll try adding method=post, although I do specify post in the ajax submit.

Comment: Added post and a csrf token, still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the case but are sure there are no spelling mistake server side? like you would be using $_FILE instead of $_FILES? Could you post the relevant php also?

Also, definitely not an issue but it is recommended to close your input tags, now like this:

```
<input ... />
```

Comment: Hah, the server side is python, not php, so it's a little more complicated. However, the issue is that the file is actually not in the post at all-- I print out all of the post vars server side and it's just not there, though everything else is. Thanks for the input tags tip.

Comment: Not exactly the problem (see my answer below) but I'll give credit because this is the only answer that addresses server side errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute to your form.

Comment: still no, and I need the display:none, because I need it to be hidden until the click. When it gets dialog()ed the display:none goes away, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the type of the input `imageurl` from `url` to `text`:

FROM:

```
<label>url: </label><input name="imageurl" type="url"><br/>
```

TO:

```
<label>url: </label><input name="imageurl" type="text"><br/>
```

I am not sure, but maybe the jquery plugin fails serializing the form due to invalid type attribute of `image_url`.

Comment: unfortunately, as expected, I did get the imageurl field but not imagefile.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you just forgot to add ---> enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form tag. This will help you out.

Comment: see DalSoft's answer... I added that attribute and it did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with the binding in javascript not recognising your file.

Try binding your submit trigger event with another live() function

i.e. change

```
$(".suggestionsubmit").submit(mooFar(e));
```

to

```
$(".suggestionsubmit").live('submit', mooFar(e));
```

Comment: as above, I think you misunderstand the question. The event fires, the form posts, I just don't get all of my inputs.

Comment: i completely understood the question; the form is broken because it's being dynamically loaded.  that's the only difference. this is a solution to make sure that you're posting the dynamically loaded form fully.

have you tried this???

Comment: No, it *isn't* being dynamically loaded. It's on the page, it's just being made into a dialog, but the code for it is *there*. And both forms are being loaded the same way, so that's not "the only difference"-- there is no difference.

Comment: when i say 'dynamically loaded', i'm talking about it being 'display: none' and and you load it into a dialog.  Your other form doesn't have this styling and when i asked previously you said the other form wasn't dynamically loaded.

you're saying the the other form does start with display:none now?  maybe you should update the code in your question to reflect this.

Comment: i had almost exactly the same problem around 2 months ago with a custom submit functionality not being very happy after i'd changed the display from 'none' to 'block'.

Answer (score 0):

...........I was looking in the wrong place in the request for the file.

Server side should have been:

```
if not s.url_field and 'imagefile' in request.FILES:
    s.image_field = request.FILES['imagefile']
```

instead of

```
s.image_field = request.POST.get('imagefile', None)
```

Complete and utter fail on my part.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the files you're testing aren't outside the max file size, it would be worth setting this in your HTML.

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="500" />
```

Also, testing without the display:none might be worth while until you have the form working; which browser are you testing in?

Comment: testing in nightly and chromium, but I'm using the same files I've used in other parts of the site...

Comment: are you using javascript to post both of these forms? is it the same javascript for both pages?

are you dynamically loading the other form which works?

Comment: i think you have a problem with the binding in javascript not recognising your HTML.

Comment: I don't think so... the form SENDS, I just don't get everything.